# How can i type in the console of vscode just like in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, console

After installing java extension pack, I start my migration trip on writing java code in vscode. But i have problem when i want to type in console to convert some values into the program such as use Scanner to get the value typed from console. What should I do, or are there any alternative method to achieve this?

Comment: for example, while hacking some ACM or algorithm codes, its quite common to use InputStreamReader and typically values is typed into console in the IDE eclipse. So how to achieve this in vscode

Comment: What do you mean by type in the console? You mean write in the console like this: `System.out("Hello world")`?

Comment: Also what do you mean by "convert some values into the program"? Do you mean for example convert a numeric value to a string to be able to output it to the console?

Comment: As a remark, I can't understand why you switch from a highly-sophisticated Java IDE like Eclipse to a one-size-fits-all thing like vscode, and then ask for features missing there.

Comment: @FelipeCenteno I mean
```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int valueFromConsole = sc.nextInt();
```

Comment: @RalfKleberhoff i will think about this...

Comment: so are you trying to find the terminal in vscode, so that you can give user input to your program? That should be under View -> Terminal

Comment: Was that what you were looking for? I'm having a hard time understanding exactly what is that you're trying to do

Comment: @FrankChen I answered your question. Let me know if that makes sense, and if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

So what you're trying to accomplish is provide user input from the terminal. What you're seeing is the debug console which is only available if you debug your application. Since your app is running. It's in read-only mode.

[image]

I hope this helps. Cheers!

Comment: Sorry, i am not getting you. While in debug model, my terminal shows the command line like this "C:\Users\Lenovo>", and I don't know how to type in.

Comment: You are trying to provide user input so even if you're in debug mode you provide user input in the terminal. Just click on the tab that says "terminal" and you should be able to provide user input.

Comment: Also you might be in debug mode, but there is no break point. Without a break point the program is going to keep running as normal. If you want to set a break point left click next to the line number where you want to set it, just to the left of the line of code number.

Comment: In your case `int num1 = sc.nextInt();` is in line 10, so click to the left of the 10 to set a break point there.